# How to save a file in vim editor without quit

Tags: vim

I know the basic command ESC + SHIFT ZZ and another ESC + :wq ENTER but i don't want to quit vim editor.I want to save the file and the file should remain open in vim.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is `:w` but I'm pretty sure that's a duplicate.

Comment: I don't know if I should vote to close this question....  There could be many similar Qs coming, like "how to move curse up/down/left/right", "how to quit without saving", "how to undo/redo"...

Comment: @DarshanSharma  The most important command in vim you should learn is not `:w`, it is `:h`, do `:h wq` you can see many possibilities to save/quit/discard....

Comment: @DarshanSharma you may want to play `vimtutor` first. just type the command in your terminal.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

<kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The `w` is "write", the `q` is "quit"; use only "write".

Answer (score 5):

Here's another shorcut that works, if you're interested in saving a keystroke or two. Run the below commands (as long as your Vim(rc) config file matches the below target destination):

```
`$ echo "noremap ww :w<CR>" >> ~/.vimrc`
`$ source ~/.vimrc`    .
```

This should add a line to your Vim config file, `noremap ww :w<CR>`, which:
(1.) Declares it's going to create a new Normal-Mode "Remap" (`noremap`); (2.) Designates what we can consider a new operator, or operating keystroke, `ww`, for the...; (3.) ...for the operand command, `:w<CR>`, which stands for "[Enter the] command mode, with ':', then key stroke 'w', following with a Carrige Return ()", and is the how the operator will behave when called. In case you're not familiar with Vim's Normal mode shortcuts: For example, using my example, you'd literally just type the letters 'ww', and read the bottom for confirmation that lines were written. (There are no "CTRL-... or CMD- or Shift-"-like combinations necessary.)

Comment: I really appreciate answers like this. It may go beyond the scope of the question, but I searched for and found this question because I'm still fairly novice with Vim, and am trying to learn basic things.  This answer provided a bit of extra information in an easily digestible quantity to not only accomplish the task I set out to learn, but dip my toe into a slightly more advanced feature that would be less likely for me to end up deciding to search for explicitly. Thanks, @Levi Maes

Comment: That being said, it does appear that this specific remap appears to interfere with using `w` to navigate.  `w` is supposed to jump to the beginning of a word, but that seems to be getting ignored with the `ww` remap.  `W` to jump forward a word still works.

Answer (score 0):

Levi Maes suggestion works except that `'w'` command is made slower. IMHO it is better  to use `:wq<CR>` just because it is easier to remember as `'write & quit'`

Answer (score -4):

Press "esc" symbol  and type "wq!".
Then this command will save the file and exit from vi editor to Command line.

Comment: Uh, that's the opposite of what OP want.